# How hot is the outer casing of a turbofan engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, engine, turbofan, engine-design

I am able to find temperatures inside different components of turbofan engines, but I can't seem to find what would be the temperature of the external casing/shell of the engine. For example, temperature of the casing around the LPC, HPC, HPT, LPT etc.
Information related to any type of turbofan engine would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tough question to answer. Because the outer casing is exposed to the elements, the temperature will vary by a tremendous amount. Temperature at cruising altitude can get down to -57C (-70F). At that temperature and a cruising speed of 450 knots, the outer casing would be rather cold. If you are talking about an aircraft sitting on the ramp, the engine will not be generating the same thrust as it would in flight, therefore, less heat. Is it raining or snowing? Winter in Alberta or summer in Florida? There are many variables.

Comment: He might mean the outer casing of the core, which might heat the bypass air slightly.

Comment: The core of a TF has its own cowl. The bypass air flows past the core cowl so the heat picked up would be insignificant.  The hottest area is the turbine casing and tail pipe where you normally have overheat warning loops for fire detection.  Forward of that, a lot of the heat under the core cowl is coming from the bleed plumbing.  To quantify, you would need an under-cowl temperature study for a particular engine that was the basis for the engine's overheat detection system, and for that you'd have to try to get something from a manufacturer's engineering organization.

Comment: Thanks guys.
I'm asking about the casing (inside the cowling) of hot components of the engine such as the HPC and HPT in maximum operating conditions. As for as the particular engine, I'd like to know about Rolls Royce's Trent 900.

Information is difficult to obtain from online sources so if you guys can help out that would be very appreciated. Thanks.